# Select values that are not included on a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table "Cells" with Primary key "Cell_ID". There are 160 ID's/records. There is one other table, for example "Customers" where I use a field "CellID", which is a table list using row source the field "Cell_ID" from the table "Cells".

I would like to create a query that will return me all the Cell_ID values that are not used on the Customers.CellId field.

My first thought was to use something like the following:

```
SELECT Cells.Cell_ID
FROM Cells
WHERE Cells.Cell_ID NOT IN (
SELECT Customers.CellID
FROM Customers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is conceptually okay.  But there is a problem if `Customers.CellId` is ever `NULL`.  If that is the case, then the query will return no rows.

For this reason, I recommend never using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.Cell_ID
FROM Cells as c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Customers as cu
                  WHERE c.Cell_ID = cu.CellID
                 );
```

Comment: I need more reputation to be able to vote but THAT WORKED! Thank you very much